# Why are weird black lines showing on my texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

On my model I got a material that was a solid beige image. I hooked it upped to some nodes, just texture coordinates and image texture. Then I assigned it to my feet and hands faces of my model and weird lines appeared as shown in the image below. The second picture shows the texture. The third image shows the weird lines on the feet. The lines are on the hands and the head too. I also have the nodes setup for the beige material. The last image is the foot UVS.[image: Nodes][image: texture] How can I fix this?[image: Weird lines]
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to add a screenshot of your node setup, also consider uploading a.blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Timaroberts Well I can't do the .blend because the textures wouldn't be there for you, but I did the nodes!

Comment: You can pack them by going to *File>External Data> Pack all into .blend* Otherwise, check your normals (`Ctrl+N` in edit mode with all selected) and that smooth shading is on and see how that does.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from your UV-map?

Comment: Don't you have a bump map applied also ?

Comment: @Yvain Do I want a bump map or not?

Comment: Hey everybody I recalculated normal and it was solved! Thanks to everyone who left a comment to help!